# Customize export output format of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, export, primefaces-datatable

I have a Primefaces dataTable where one column is having three output texts and one command button with tooltip. The button appears with output labels as

> This is for export label. This is for text.org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@3f60d3f9

How can I not include/print this command button with tooltip to export the dataTable to excel?

I can't move the command button to new column for business case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PrimeFaces you can override the exported content of a column by using the `exportFunction` attribute (which is in the documentation). If you'd read this in the documentation, you'd easily have found https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=50284 by using google. In it, an example is given of how to override the 'exported value' of a column:

XHTML:

```
<p:column exportFunction="#{testView.exportBrand}">
   <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Brand" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>
```

Java:

```
public String exportBrand(UIColumn column) {
    String value = "";
    for(UIComponent child: column.getChildren()) {
        if(child instanceof ValueHolder) {
            value = ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), child);
        }
    }
    
    return value + "_TEST";
}
```

Just extend this and in the for loop only export things you want to export.

Comment: Apart from above export function, We can also use postProcessor and preProcessor as documented @ [PrimeFaces ShowCase] https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml to further customize our export documents

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to @Kukeltje's answer I like to mention that you can also specify your own method parameter (instead of using `UIColumn`):

Facelet:

```
<p:column exportFunction="#{testView.exportBrand(car)}">
   <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Brand" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>
```

Backing bean:

```
public String exportBrand(Car car) {
    if (car == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return car.getBrand();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day; it's more convenient than using the method with UIColumn parameter