# How to prevent convertNumber if dataTable is exported via dataExporter

Tags: primefaces

If I export my dataTable to Excel with dataExporter the numbers getting spaces in it and I can't convert them in Excel to numbers and  summarize them.

I tried with the exportFunction, but I wasn't able to get that to work. But I think it wouldn't matter, because of the convertNumber function.

```
    <p:column filterBy="#{item.netPrice}" filterStyle="width: 65px;" exportFunction="#{controller.exportNumber}" headerText="#{bundle.ListFormItemSumTitle_netPrice}" filterMatchMode="startsWith" sortBy="#{item.netPrice}" visible="#{controller.isColumnVisible[1]}">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.netPrice}">
            <f:convertNumber />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
```

Controller method:

```
    public String exportNumber(UIColumn column) {
        String value = "";
        for(UIComponent child: column.getChildren()) {
            if(child instanceof ValueHolder) {
                value = ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), child);
            }
        }

        return value.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

This method wasn't even called at export sadly... :(

This is one of the columns.

```
<p:column filterBy="#{item.netPrice}" filterStyle="width: 65px;" headerText="#{bundle.ListForm_netPrice}" filterMatchMode="startsWith" sortBy="#{item.netPrice}" visible="#{controller.isColumnVisible[1]}">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.netPrice}">
            <f:convertNumber />
        </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Expected result: if I export the dataTable the numbers doesn't include spaces, If I view the dataTable on the UI, the spaces are there as thousend separator.

Primefaces version:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId> 
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId> 
<version>6.2</version> 
<type>jar</type> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe your PF version does not support the `exportFunction`.... Checked that? (posting version info in your questions should always be done btw)

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

Comment: In the question please... That is the better place. And did you try with less attributes on the column? No filter, no sort, no visible? Since a plain solution certainly works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250348/customize-export-output-format-of-pdatatable

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is with the syntax. How can I pass the UIColumn parameter to the controller.exportNumber function? I don't know how to access this variable the from the xhtml... Because without parameter the function is not called.

Comment: Did you see the second answer in the link? It passes A parameter, not specifically a UIColumn.